# Android Fragments Displaying On Top Of Each Other When Screen Orientation Changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a navigation menu, which displays various modes of operation to the user. When the user selects a specific option, the activity is to load the corresponding fragment (Eg: Add Product should load the AddProduct fragment).

The loading works fine - I used FragmentManager together with FragmentTransaction to replace the current fragment with the new fragment. The problem comes in when the screen gets rotated - the current two fragments I have used, display on top of each other.

Here is the code I have set up for the NavigationDrawerListener (the part that does the loading):

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) currentActivty.findViewById(R.id
            .homeDrawer);
    TextView heading = (TextView) currentActivty.findViewById(R.id.AppHeadingTextView);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            heading.setText("Home");
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            UserMainScreenFragment homeScreen = new UserMainScreenFragment();
            FragmentManager homeManager = currentActivty.getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction homeTransaction = homeManager.beginTransaction();
            homeTransaction.replace(R.id.contentArea, homeScreen);
            homeTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            heading.setText("Add a Product");
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            AddProductFragment newProductFragment = new AddProductFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = currentActivty.getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction replace = manager.beginTransaction();
            replace.replace(R.id.contentArea, newProductFragment);
            replace.commit();
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate layout for required activity according to orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add different layout's (with same name) for both orientations, then Android will automatically inflate the suitable xml according to the orientation.

File structure will look like this,

```
res
 - drawable
 - layout                        // for portrait
    - layout_name.xml            
 - layout-land                   // for landscape
    - layout_name.xml            // same name should be used
 - .....
```

Find a sample solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976114/how-can-i-change-the-ui-when-in-portrait-and-landscape/33976267#33976267)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you need to check for savedInstanceState being null to avoid adding the same fragments again:

```
//when the orientation changes, the savedInstanceState bundle is not null
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
//add your fragment to the layout
}
```

another thing, I noticed you reference the fragment manager through currentActivty.getFragmentManager();

maybe the **currentActivty.getFragmentManager();** has an old reference to the activity that gets destroyed, you should also use **getSupportFragmentManager()** if you're using the support library